# Non-uppercase constants in Java

Tags: java, naming-conventions, constants

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838929/naming-why-should-named-constants-be-all-uppercase-in-c-java) about why constants in Java are uppercase by convention made me try to think of counter examples.

I can think of at least one (`Double.NaN`). Are there others?

Comment: Shouldn't this be a Community Wiki?

Comment: Is this interesting or useful?  How does it help you or anyone do your job?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are lots of `serialVersionUID`!

Others in `ResultSetMetaData` like `columnNoNulls`, `columnNullable`...
`DatabaseMetaData` and `ICC_Profile` have lots of mixed case constants.

Here is a list with most, if not all, JavaSE constants: [Constant Field Values](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.awt.color.ICC_Profile.icHdrPlatform)

Comment: The link to all of the constants make this a winner!

Answer (score 7):

Of course, `public final static PrintStream out` (in `java.lang.System.out`). But it's a very good exception, because `System.OUT.println` is just ugly.

Also, most of the time loggers are initialized as follows:

```
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class);
```

However, in both cases these are not constants in the true sense of the term. So perhaps we can make a distinction:

Fields that are `static` because they need a static access, and `final` because they should not be re-assigned at runtime, are not necessarily *constants*.

Comment: I agree; I believe that constants are always value objects (immutable ones at that, of course).

Comment: I agree. Upper-case should be reserved for *immutable* constants, not simply anything `static` and `final`.

Answer (score 2):

Color constants like black, red, green etc from [java.awt.Color](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html) class.

It should be noted that [java.awt.Color](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html) also provides the uppercase alternatives (e.g. BLACK, RED, GREEN etc) of these constants.

Answer (score 2):

java.util.logging.Logger.global is a constant with all lowercase

Answer (score 0):

`null`, `true` and `false`. They are arguably keywords, but when you get down to it, they're constants evaluating to 0x00, 0x01 and 0x00 respectively.

Comment: In C++ perhaps, but certainly not in java. There's no `(int) null` or `(int) true`

Comment: Also: they are literals, not keywords. Just as `13` is a literal or `"foo"`.

Comment: You are probably confused with Boolean.TRUE and Boolean.FALSE which are constants but uppercase.

Comment: No, I'm not really confused. While they _are_ literals, and they _are_ keywords (of a sort), they are also symbolic constants. `null` is a constant reference to a type `null` of which `null` is the only instance (Java Language Spec). I think the same is true of `true` and `false`.

Comment: The point remains that your declaration that null/true/false "evaluate to" 0/1/0 is bizarre.  There is no such association between Object references and integral values or between booleans and integral values in the Java language.  Were you pitching your answer at VM engineers?

Comment: They are not 'keywords of a sort'. They are literals. See the Java grammar.

Answer (score 0):

The `length` of array instances.

Btw, I see examples mentioned of objects that are "constant" in one respect, namely their reference does not change - the reference is a final static, but when those objects are active; i.e. their internal attributes do change when methods on these objects are called. In those cases I would not use the UPPERCASE naming convention as the objects are no constants in my view.