# Why aren't constants all in upper-case in .Net?

Tags: .net, naming-conventions, constants

Microsoft naming conventions for .Net put constants in Pascal Case. In fact, it explicitly tells us to avoid using all caps for constants:

> You might also have to capitalize
>   identifiers to maintain compatibility
>   with existing, unmanaged symbol
>   schemes, where all uppercase
>   characters are often used for
>   enumerations and constant values. In
>   general, these symbols should not be
>   visible outside of the assembly that
>   uses them.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2dbyw72(v=VS.71).aspx).

On SO I found some questions on the subject, like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838929/naming-why-should-named-constants-be-all-uppercase-in-c-java), but I couldn't find a rationale. So, anyone know or have a reference that points to why MS chose this convention?

Comment: BECAUSE ALL-UPPERCASE IS HARD TO READ AND IT'S INTENDED FOR THE PRECOMPILER, WHICH .NET DOESN'T EVEN HAVE.

Comment: Ok, I'll make it an official answer.

Comment: After decades of C# programming I still use all caps for CONSTANTS because it's faster and easier to pick out of intellitype suggestions when doing seriously large coding.

Comment: @JohnC - Ditto.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Its just a style guideline. Programming languages have started to recommend and push formatting conventions so that code is more readable.

Also, symbols that get substituted by the preprocessor deserve special attention-- they live outside/before the type system and may not be what they appear to be. Constants are just constants, they won't change at compile or runtime.

Comment: If you think about the history, uppercase was used for C preprocessor symbols, so when C++ came out and had `const`, those symbols were kept mixed case. C# and Java both come from C++, so they follow the C++ convention.

Comment: On a side note, let's not forget that a `const` is purely compile-time while a `static readonly` is there at runtime, which is why only the former is allowed as a default value in C# 4.

Comment: On second reading, I have a nit to pick: the purpose of naming standards and formatting conventions isn't just to make code more readable but to make it mutually intelligible. There's no great reason why .NET recommends MixedCase for methods instead of camelCase, but if everyone uses the same one of these two choices, we can read each other's code without getting confused or annoyed. It's like driving on the right side of the street instead of the left: doesn't really matter, so long as everyone picks the same side.

Comment: Yes I agree, and that was my intention, "more readable", by others, not just the original author. If people are not having to constantly adjust to different styles they can absorb the semantics of the code quicker-- especially if it was not written by them. And this is a stance taken by C# and Python notably, greater gains (for everyone) are realized from a consistent style than allowing the flexibility of any style like C/C++.

Comment: @Steveb Sudit const isn't necessarily compile-time; constexpr should be though.

Comment: Thumbs up for saying "guideline". :)

Comment: I find `MY_CONSTANT` to be more readable than `MyConstant` because as soon as I look at it I know that it is an immutable value.  It is also why I always make my enums all caps.   And I can tell an enum from a constant because `MyEnum.ENUM_VALUE0` scopes it for me.

Answer (score 5):

BECAUSE ALL-UPPERCASE IS UGLY AND HARD TO READ AND IT'S INTENDED FOR THE PRECOMPILER, WHICH .NET DOESN'T EVEN HAVE.

Also, Bill Gates wants it that way, and money is never wrong.

Comment: And with Resharper (maybe even VS) you can type MCVTNC for MyConstantValueThatNeverChanges, but that won't work for all caps.

Comment: I don't think that the acronym works in the selection list, at least not for VS 2008.

Answer (score 4):

Saying that all caps is ugly and thus should not be used is borderline childish logic.  It comes from people complaining about what they are not used to.

Having gone from Java to C, I started using underscores_between_words in variable names and functions. camelCase is *extremely* ugly to me now.  But I still use camelCase for C++/Java without complaining because it is convension.

If you can't make yourself flexible, programming will become a harsh mistress.  That is the skill of a programmer.

Comment: No, it's objectively bad: all-uppercase is simply hard to read. I started with all-uppercase because that's the only option under EBCDIC. Now that we have mixed-case, case-sensitive languages using ASCII, we have better options.

Comment: @Steven: I have to disagree. Pizzach is right -- ALL_UPPER is just text, and I haven't heard of a statistic that proved it's harder to read than small case. I'd make just one quick note, having underscores separating words costs one more character in the word, so we have "wider" or "lengthier" code, which is bad.

Comment: @Bruno: Capital letters are more similar in shape than lower-case ones, which is why they're harder to read. To quote Wikipedia, "owever, long spans of Latin-alphabet text in all upper-case are harder to read because of the absence of the ascenders and descenders found in lower-case letters, which can aid recognition."

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft doesn't following its own rules because if you reflect over the new System.Threading.Tasks classes in c# 4 YOU_WILL_FIND_LOTS_OF_CAP_CONSTANTS.

Its a style thing. Personally I don't mind. Just be consistent.

Comment: It's true; if you look at .Net internals, you also find lots of `m_` usages, despite this being evil, forbidden Hungarian notation.

Comment: Even the latest source code of .NET Core contains several uppercase constants defined: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs

Comment: And a lot of the example code on MS pages uses `_classVariable` even though their guidelines says that class variables should have no prefix.  I find some kind of class variable prefix preferable so I know where to look for variable declaration.  What prefix?  I don't care.  Just be consistent.  As someone mentioned above, consistency is king.

Answer (score 1):

Just as a BTW -- EBCDIC is the *extended* version of BCD (binary coded decimal), and as such certainly supports lower case.  It's the 60s vintage and earlier IBM machines (and others) that did not include lower case.

(And, of course, early home computers like the TRS-80 didn't have lower case, either)

Comment: You're right: EBCDIC does support lower-case. However, as far as I can remember, the punch-card machines I used with the IBM 370 did not offer any way to enter lower-case characters.