# Changing from #define to const (uppercase?)

Tags: c++

I'm doing a bit of refactoring on some code and I'm seeing `#define` used a lot to create constants. From what I read I understand that consts with the proper type would be better.

But what about the naming style? Should I keep the uppercase for the `const`s or it should be used exclusively for macros?

```
#define MINUTE_LEN 6
#define SECOND_LEN 6
#define MILISECOND_LEN 11
```

Should be:

```
const int MINUTE_LEN = 6;
const int SECOND_LEN = 6;
const int MILISECOND_LEN = 11;
```

or:

```
const int minuteLen = 6;
const int secondLen = 6;
const int milisecondLen = 11;
```

What is recommended? I feel like the uppercase helps to identify that it is a constant.

**Edit:** As long as it may be opinion-based, there might be objective reasons supporting some style or the other. As Mark Ransom pointed out, there's no rule saying macros need to be upper-case either. But there is a *de facto* convention to use uppercase for macros, to avoid mixing them with variable names (cannot be detected earlier and causes a broken code).

Comment: It's a stylistic convention to indicate the number is a constant. There's no rule saying macros need to be upper-case either. I suspect the convention originated to make sure macros didn't inadvertently mess with other parts of the code such as variable or function names.

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/838929/naming-why-should-named-constants-be-all-uppercase-in-c-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what style you want to adopt but keep it consistent.

Generally, all uppercase is used for macros, so you could go for Pascal Case/UpperCamelCase.

As a side note, if you know the value is not going to change during compile time and you can compile using >= C++ 11, then you should most definitely aim for using `constexpr` wherever possible.